# PHP Register didnt working

Tags: php

hi i was created a php register page for my site,and this page didint work corectly.I dnt have db erorr but cant create a new user.
First time when i create a new user in db,there was a new user but withuot username and password.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$con = mysql_connect('fdb13.biz.nf','xxx','yyy');
mysql_select_db('1846946_chat',$con);

$uname1= $POST['username'];
$pword1= $POST['password'];
$pword2= $POST['password2'];

if($pword1 != $pword2){
echo "Pasvordi se ne poklapaju!<br>";
}
else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM korisnici WHERE username='$uname1'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) echo "Username vec postoji,izaberi drgaciji<br>";

else{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO korisnici (username,password) VALUES ('$uname1','$pword1')");
echo "Uspesno si se registroavao.Klikni <a href='index.php'>ovde</a> da zapocnes chat!<br>";
}
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form name="forma1" method="post" action="register.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Unesi username: <input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Unesi password: <input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ponovi password: <input type="password" name="password2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registruj"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><a href="index.php" class="button">Vrati se na login!</a><br></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with this. First, use PDO instead of `mysql_`. Next you need to hash your passwords, never store plain text passwords. Third, , you don't even check if the `$_POST` variables are defined or not, check them with `isset()`. The list can go on.

Comment: There are SQL injection problems here, and I can't see any attempt to prevent duplicate usernames being inserted.

Comment: (If the database credentials in the edit history are your real details, change them in your database **now**, otherwise you may be at risk of having your data stolen or sabotaged).

Comment: `$POST` missing underscore for all, so do `$_POST` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, which would have triggered the syntax errors.